# Windows batch, select ONLY user variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

In environment variables I have a PATH variable for both user variables and system variables.

In a batch script, in order for me to append the user PATH variable with a new given path, I need to select the current value. Unfortunately %PATH% returns a combination of the user variable and the system variable.

Of course I only want to add a new custom path value to the user variable. There is no point in enhancing it with the system path as well. That's why I have 2 variables.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Found in the documentation the following statement:

The %PATH% variable is set as both a system and user variable, the 2 values are combined to give the PATH for the currently logged in user....

Example:

User variables:

```
PATH
value: c:\dev
```

System variables

```
PATH
value: c:\Program Files
```

What I want to do, is to add to the user variable the value: c:\tmp, so that in the end PATH will have the value: c:\dev;c:\tmp

But, if open a cmd window:

```
echo %PATH%
c:\Program Files;c:\dev
```

so the setx will do the following

```
setx path "%path%;c:\tmp"
```

open new cmd

```
echo %PATH%
c:\Program Files;c:\dev;c:\tmp
```

And that is wrong, because I only needed c:\dev;c:\tmp

I hope I was more clear this time.

Comment: If you already have a `USERPATH` then why not simply add to `%USERPATH%`?

Comment: I don't have a %USERPATH%. Both variables are called %PATH%

Comment: You should probably give an example, I don't get it from your description at all.

Comment: So in a nutshell, you want to `echo` the user `path`, rather than the combined system and user?

Comment: yes :). Because setting it is clear, but I need to know to what I am setting it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How are you modifying the variables?

There is only one environment variable `PATH`, so you can go ahead and change it. These changes are transient (and local to your process and its children).

There are two (actually more) persistent places in Registry from which the environment variables are initialized when a process is created. You can modify them using [`reg`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490984.aspx) utility. There is no ambiguity since they are separate:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

You may have to re-login for changes in Registry to take effect (I don't remember whether there's a programmatic way to notify explorer that these settings have changed). Also note that by default child processes inherit the environment of their parent (unless the parent takes special measures to do otherwise), so e.g. if you launch a `cmd` window and later modify the environment via system settings dialog, applications started from that `cmd` won't see the changes.

**[UPD]** You can get the value of user-specific environment variable from registry using `reg` utility:

```
reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH
```

Though you'll have to filter its output for the actual value, as it spits out some useless text. Here an example incantation:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2,*" %A in (`reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH`) do set value=%B
```

It will store the result in the environment variable `value`. Remember to double `%`'s when using it in a batch file.

Comment: I was already trying to get the value from registry, but you gave me the command quicker :) I'll see if I can clean the output. I'll update my question if I do. Thx a lot.

Comment: Thanks again :) Day by day I am reminded why I love Linux bash scripting rather then windows batch.

Comment: @bioShark yes, writing batch is always a peculiar experience :)  Note that I had to edit this one-liner *again* as previous version didn't handle spaces correctly.

Comment: To notify all top-level windows (including Explorer) when updating the registry environment settings, send a [`WM_SETTTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497) message with `lParam` set to `L"Environment"`. Explorer calls the undocumented function `shell32!RegenerateUserEnvironment` to reload its environment. Note that `setx.exe` sends the `WM_SETTTINGCHANGE` message, but reg.exe does not. cmd.exe, like most console applications, doesn't own a top-level window to listen for this message, so only subsequent instances of cmd.exe have the updated environment.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you have 2 `%PATH%` variables. One system one, and one user one, (presumably you created the latter yourself).

I have tried this and it seems to work for user environment variables

```
setx /s computername PATH %PATH%;newpathvalue
```

When I tested this I actually substituted `PATH` for a new var to make sure it works, but it may be best making a copy of your existing vars before doing this, just in case.

It will tag onto the end of the existing user environment variable `PATH` with the new value you specify, separating it from the others with a semi-colon `;`.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is working, but the problem is that %PATH% (the value of the PATH, when you make an echo) combines the 2 PATH variables. Extracted from original documentation: The %PATH% variable is set as both a system and user variable, the 2 values are combined to give the PATH for the currently logged in user.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your trying to accomplish, are you trying to echo just the user %path%?

Comment: I'll update my original question with a more detailed example. give me 2 minutes.