# How to return only user Path in environment variables without access to Registry?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, path, environment-variables

Here is what I want to achieve: 
I am coding a Python based software, which will need to append new directories to **PATH** in environment variables in Windows. In order to do that, I first get the path, then modify the string, and last use SETX to update the new PATH.

My problem: 
I tried three methods to get PATH (with python or cmd), but they all returns me the combination of USER PATH and SYSTEM PATH. The three methods are:

```
os.environ['PATH']
os.system('echo %PATH%')
os.system('set PATH')
```

I cannot accept the combination of user path and system path, because this would result in new user PATH being too long, and being truncated to 1024 characters (limitation by Microsoft). I have read a post with the exact same problem. The problem seems to be solved by using Registry in that case: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359082/windows-batch-select-only-user-variables](http://%20only%20user%20Path%20in%20environment%20variables%20without%20access%20to%20Registry). The solution suggest using

```
reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH
```

to access registry where the user variables and system variables are separated.
But the solution does not work for me.  When I run it on commend line, it returns me "Access is denied". 
As a result, I am looking for method that return only user Path in environment variables without access to Registry. Thank you.

Comment: Storing the expanded and concatenated `%PATH%` to the user's `PATH` value in the registry is wrong regardless of the length limit imposed by older versions.

Comment: I can't think of a reason for being denied access to `HKCU\Environment`. This is located in the user's registry hive stored in the user profile ntuser.dat. Are you sure the error isn't that it's unable to find a value named `PATH`? It's normal for the user value to not exist. You just have to create a new value.

Comment: eryksun, I agree with you that storing %PATH% to user path is totally wrong. And, yes, I am sure that the error message of access registry says "Access is denied." I am using a cooperate computer and maybe that's the reason why. I would appreciate if anyone can provide me any information of how to solve the problem.

Comment: Check `import _winreg;` `key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Environment', 0, _winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)`. If it fails with access denied, there's no way you can modify the key's values. In that case look at the permissions on the key in regedit to see which users and groups are allowed to modify it.

Comment: `pathman` would be a more appropriate tool than `setx`, but I'm not sure whether it is still available.

Comment: Hi @eryksun, I tested your code in Python and it succeeded. Then I typed 'value, _ = _winreg.QuaryValueEx(key,"PATH")', it returns "WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied".  I am a little fuzzy about using _winreg. Do you see anything that I can do?

Comment: Hi @Harry Johnston, I did a quick search and did not find pathman.

Comment: To query values you have to request `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` access. Please familiarize yourself with [registry key access rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724878).

Comment: @HarryJohnston, the nice thing about setx.exe is that it broadcasts the `L"Environment"` `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message for you. Doing that in Python requires ctypes or PyWin32. I think it would be a useful enhancement for scripting if `winreg` had a simple function to broadcast this message.

Comment: setx.exe also automatically selects the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type if the data string has 2 or more percent characters. So it should be run using `subprocess.call` *without* `shell=True`. You don't want cmd to expand percent variables in a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value before setx.exe sees them. You want them to be expanded when the user's profile is loaded, or when Explorer calls `shell32!RegenerateUserEnvironment` in response to a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message.

Comment: @eryksun: it's been a while since I've used it, but I'm pretty sure `pathman` broadcasts the settings change message too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import _winreg
import unicodedata
keyQ = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Environment', 0, _winreg.KEY_QUERY_VALUE)
path_old, _ = _winreg.QueryValueEx(keyQ, "PATH")
#the result is unicode, need to be converted
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', path_old).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Although I said I want an answer without access to registry, it turns out this is the only way to get user environment variable "PATH". Thank you everyone.